# How do I cancel a job trigger if the previous trigger is still running?

Tags: quartz-scheduler

i am new to Quartz scheduler. i have one batch file, it will take 3mins to run. i need to run this batch every 2 mins using Quartz scheduler. so i scheduled it for 3 hrs daily.
my problem is i need to check the status of the first trigger and if it is not complete state i need to come out from this job . and i need to proceed with the next job i scheduled.
explanation:
job 53 trigger starts at 11.30 am
next trigger starts at 11.32am
next trigger starts at 11.34am
i need to check 11.30am trigger status  and  if it is not compeletd i need to shutdown this job and go to the next job i scheduled. how can achieve this in Quartz scheduler

Answer (score 1):

You can get currently executing jobs from the `Scheduler` and check is your job completed or not:

```
Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
List jobsList = scheduler.getCurrentlyExecutingJobs();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the trigger instance,starts at 11.30am then just check is "trigger.STATE_BLOCKED"
equalto 1 or no. If it 1, then job is in running state.